# delete tmux socket file created with -S after session exit

Tags: tmux, socket

I create a `tmux` session and want to share it with a different user. So I start `tmux` like this:

```
tmux -S /tmp/tmuxshareds new-session -s 'mysession'
chgrp tmuxshare /tmp/tmuxshareds
```

This works fine but when exiting the `tmux` session (exiting all programs in all panes), the file `/tmp/tmuxshareds` is still there.

Is there a way to let `tmux` delete the file after the session is closed?

Answer (score 0):

No tmux does not delete sockets, you will need to do it yourself.